# Access websites with iFrame <X-Frame-Options>

Tags: iframe, whatsapp, x-frame-options

I need to have https://web.whatsapp.com embedded in my website via iframe. I get the error of `X-Frame-Options`. I use express server and I tried to configure it with `helmet`:

```
app.use(
    helmet.frameguard({
        action: "sameorigin",
    })
)
```

Doesn't seem to work. Same with `deny`. I read that `ALLOW-FROM` is not supported in Chrome browser anymore. Is there any chance to bypass or allow `X-Frame-Options` to accept certain origins? (Maybe there is any other options how to embed https://web.whatsapp.com to my website?).

Answer (score 0):

X-Frame-Options prevents a site from being framed. As web.whatsapp.com prevents framing, there is nothing you can do to allow it being framed, unless you proxy the connection and remove headers. Adding headers to the site framing the other won't change anything.